# Modify xml document using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to understand if there is a way to modify an xml document using XSLT or are there any other better approaches than XSLT?

Say, I have an xml like so:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id>http://libx.org/libx2/libapps</id>
<entry>
<id>http://libx.org/libx2/libapps/2</id>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>http://libx.org/libx2/libapps/3</id>
</entry>
</feed>
```

I would like to do the following actions:

1. Modify feed:id to  (remove the text of feed:id)
2. Modify entry:id values such that the last number value after "/" remains.

The result xml should look something like so:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<id></id>
<entry>
<id>2</id>
</entry>
<entry>
<id>3</id>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: Good question, +1. Yes, this is easy in XSLT 1.0 and trivial in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I. XSLT 1.0 solution:

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation** works with any url without having any assumptions about all URLs haing a common starting substring:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:feed/x:id/node()"/>

 <xsl:template match="x:entry/x:id/text()" name="eatSlashes">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '/'))">
    <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:call-template name="eatSlashes">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                   "substring-after($pText, '/')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>http://libx.org/libx2/libapps</id>
    <entry>
        <id>http://libx.org/libx2/libapps/2</id>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>http://libx.org/libx2/libapps/3</id>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <id/>
   <entry>
      <id>2</id>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <id>3</id>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="x:feed/x:id/node()"/>

 <xsl:template match="x:entry/x:id/text()">
  <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(.,'/')[last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <id/>
   <entry>
      <id>2</id>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <id>3</id>
   </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of XSLT isn't the best but this seems to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a:feed/a:id" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="a:entry/a:id" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'http://libx.org/libx2/libapps/')"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```